# Populate GridViewDataComboBoxColumn from database Table

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to populate `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn` from a Database Table. I have a city table and I want it to bind in `ComboBox` which is present in the `gridview(DevExpress)`.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyXHR.png)

Comment: The answer will change slightly based on the database used. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**From:** [ASPxGridView - How to set the DataSource property in code for GridViewDataComboBoxColumn column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q313706)

If you want to set a datasource for the combobox column at runtime, you should define all required **PropertiesComboBox** object properties at runtime. An approximate code should be as follows:

```
GridViewDataComboBoxColumn column = grid.Columns["Id_Dienst"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn;
column.PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = ...;
column.PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "DienstNaam";
...
```

> If you want to change the GridViewDataComboBox column's DataSource at
>   runtime. To accomplish this task handle the server-side
>   [ASPxGridView.CellEditorInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CellEditorInitializetopic) event handler. Please refer to the
>   [ASPxGridView - How to bind GridViewDataComboBoxColumn at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E3591.aspx)
>   example to know how you can bind ComboBoxColumn to the DataSource at
>   runtime using this event handler. To bind the auto filter cell's
>   ComboBox use the server-side
>   [ASPxGridView.AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_AutoFilterCellEditorInitializetopic) event handler in the same
>   manner.

If it does not meet your requirement then follow the below DevExpress thread and other reference links:

[ASPxGridView - How to bind GridViewDataComboBoxColumn with datasource at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q331933)

**References:**
[GridViewDataComboBoxColumn - how to databind at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q103592)
[ASPxGridView - How to change GridViewDataComboBoxColumn DataSource at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q456080)
[Search Results for this topic](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=aspxgridview%20gridviewdatacomboboxcolumn%20datasource)